# How to upload generated PDF to s3 using lambda and node?

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I am learning how to use Lambdas and S3 and running into an issue hopefully you can help me answer.

- I am using nodejs and serverless
- The IAM user has s3 full access for now

issue: I am trying to generate a PDF file from user input using PDF kit library (might switch to puppeteer in the future), attempting to store that file in a `/tmp/` folder and then upload it into an s3 bucket using the aws-sdk.

Locally this works perfect, however, when I try to do it on the lambda it either doesn't upload it or it uploads a file with 0 bytes.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my handler:

```
module.exports.generatePdf = async (invoiceData, context) => {
  const date = new Date().toISOString();
  const firstFour = (str) => str.split("-")[0];
  const filename = `invoice-${firstFour(String(invoiceData.invoice_id))}-${date}.pdf`;
  const pdfPath = `/tmp/${filename}`;

  const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument({ margin: 50 });
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(join("/tmp/", filename));

    pdfDoc
    .image(join(__dirname, "/assets/ds_logo.png"), 400, 35, {
      width: 150,
      height: 100,
      align: "right",
    })
    .fillColor("#444444")
    .fontSize(20)
    .fontSize(10)
    .text(data.name, 50, 35, { align: "left" })
    .text(`${datainvoiceDatahouse_number} ${invoiceData.street_address}`, 50, 45, {
      align: "left",
    })
    .text(`${invoiceData.city}, ${invoiceData.state_code}, ${invoiceData.zip}`, 50, 55, {
      align: "left",
    })
    .moveDown();  
  
  pdfDoc.end();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stats = fs.statSync(pdfPath);
    console.log("filesize: " + stats.size);
    console.log("----- startingt s3 upload -----");
    const params = {
      Key: filename,
      Body: fs.createReadStream(pdfPath),
      Bucket: "<bucket>",
      ContentType: "application/pdf",
      ContentLength: stats.size,
    };
    s3.upload(params, async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

serverless.yml:

```
service: pdfgenerator

frameworkVersion: "2"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  generatePdf:
    handler: handler.generatePdf
    memorySize: 128
    events:
      - http:
          path: pdf
          method: get
```

From random research some have suggested to wrap the `s3.upload(...` part with a `file.on("finish", () => s3.upload(..` however this seems to jus hang and not output anything.

Comment: I agree with the `.on("finish")` callback suggestion; If its hanging there, it sounds like an async issue. its always awkward using `async/await` when your handler is using callbacks. maybe switch off of async and go back to trusty callbacks https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-sync

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried it, and it works locally but no luck on lambda, it seems when I wrap it around `.on("finish")` it skips that step in lambda as a whole, it does not even output any of the console.logs I have inside